# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int' after 28 iterations

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

My code runs on a random image for 28 iterations and THEN gets the **error:**

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'`

I'm not really sure why it is getting that error after 28 iterations when it should have broken after 1 iteration only.

**My code:**

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

#import image
img = cv2.imread('small.jpg')
height,width = img.shape[:2]

#create feature vector for RGB values
#for this image length = 6536
feature = []
for i in range(0, height):
    for j in range(0, width):
        val = img[i,j]
        feature.append(val)

#find average normal value
normThreshold = 3


#function for the gaussian kernal
def gaussian(x, xi):
    h = 2
    const = 1/(np.sqrt(math.pi))
    norm_x = np.linalg.norm(x)
    norm_xi = np.linalg.norm(xi)
    output = const*(np.exp( (-1)*np.square(norm_x-norm_xi)/np.square(2*h) ))
    return output

#conduct mean shift algorithm 
for i in range(0, len(feature)):
    print (i)
    condition = True
    while(condition):
        s1 = [0,0,0]
        s2 = 0
        m = [0,0,0]
        for j in range(0, len(feature)):
            if (i != j):
                diff = np.linalg.norm(feature[i] - feature[j])
                if (diff < normThreshold and diff != 0):
                    # print (feature[j])
                    top = gaussian(feature[i],feature[j])*feature[j]
                    bottom = gaussian(feature[i],feature[j])
                    s1 += top
                    s2 += bottom
        if (gaussian(feature[i],feature[j]) != 0):
            m = s1/s2
            # print (s1)
            # print (s2)
            # print (m)
        c1 = np.linalg.norm(m)
        c2 = np.linalg.norm(feature[i])
        if (np.absolute(c1-c2) < 0.001):
            condition = False
        feature[i] = m
print("finished")
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?

Comment: @Peter I think I solved it, the issue is the "normThreshold" variable, if i set it to a higher value, this issue is resolved

Comment: @RichardWU It would be better if you post it as answer and mark correct.

Comment: @RichardWU, no, that just means that you avoided running the line of code with the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `s1` and `m` as arrays, not lists.

```
s1 = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0])
m = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Without studying the whole code or testing it, here's something that looks suspicious:

```
    s1 = [0,0,0]
    s2 = 0
    while ....
        s1 += top
        s2 += bottom
```

`+=` for a list (`s1`) is concatenate.  For an integer (`s2`) it mean add.  The `+=` appear to be similar, but are totally different because of how the 2 variables are created.

```
 m = s1/s2
```

is the one that raises the error, since `/` is not defined for a list.

Both operations are in `if` clauses.

If you want to do math on all the elements of `s1` (and `m`) you should use `np.array` instead of lists. But if using arrays you need to pay more attention to `shape` (and `dtype`).  And be careful about mixing arrays with iterative code like this.